# Await a task with popup in c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

In my Xamarin forms project, I have two popups to be shown one after another.

```
await HandlePopup1(); // Shows popup1
await HandlePopup2(); // Shows popup2
```

Here, the task for HandlePopup2 is not waiting for the popup1 to be closed.

How to handle this. TIA.

Comment: Could you add the code for `HandlePopup1()` and/or (if they are different) `HandlePopup2()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the dialog as model, though that will depend on your framework and what you are using. Or you can use an `AutoResetEvent` (or some-sort of *synchronisation object*), or if you want to get fancy one of the `async` variants that are floating around.

```
using(var resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false))
{
    await HandlePopup1(resetEvent); // Shows popup1
    // Wait
    resetEvent.WaitOne();

    await HandlePopup2(); // Shows popup2
}
```

Then in your dialog `onclosed` / `onclosing` method (or similar). Just hit `Set`.

```
resetEvent.Set()
```